# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection called multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How many times should the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method be called when populating a table view?

My application is crashing with no warnings, errors, or a stack trace. I have also tested for memory leaks and have found none. The app holds steady at about 1.4MB.

I have NSLog reporting as methods are messaged, and I notice that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is being called multiple times. The app crashes during one of these "extra" calls. The point at which the app crashes varies. I should point out that the table is populating about 600 cells, if that makes a difference.

I can post code if you want, but my data source comes from a `singleton class`, so It is a lot of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u pls post the code?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in another similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638359/uitableview-delegate-method-called-twice/4986682#4986682)
Basically, calls to the the delegate methods of a table view can be triggered by different events. It wouldn't be a suprise to me that UITableView calls `numberOfRowsInSection` multiple times (even for the same section).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, the first time tableview instance is not nil and the subsequent times it is nil. The problem was, I had yet not set the return value for

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and because of this it kept happening. Once I set a return value the problem was gone. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use [Lazy table image loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) . so that the 600 cells is a big amount and if you call all the data in a single time it will always going to be crashed due to memory issues.

try using the code I provided .

Another answer on the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531482/lazy-load-images-in-uitableviewcell)   can help you out.

Comment: Im not loading images, just text. Can the Lazy Table image loading method work for that as well?

Comment: It should work for you. as with lazy table image you can load a number of images along with text... so try and change something in the lazy table images code , make it according to your needs ... you will definitely get the answer..

Comment: Is there a certain amount of cells which would be supported? I am loading this info via a JSON string, so I get all 600+ cells of data in one call. Should I only display 50 at a time with a load more option? And if the user eventually loads all 600 is that going to be an issue? Or is there some kind of pagination technique I should be using?

Comment: That would be a better option, you can put a button at the end of 50 data , press to show more and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm confused, because the way the UITable rendering works, it only renders enough cells to fill the screen. The rest are rendered during scroll. So What difference does it make if I have 50 cells or 1000?