# Why does my tableView function run three times?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6.1.1

I have a UITableView and I have one of the required methods for its execution:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println("section is \(section)")
    println(self.items.count) // self.items.count = 3
    return self.items.count
}
```

In my log I see the method being run 3 times:

```
section is 0
3
section is 0
3
section is 0
3
```

EDIT:

This is the snippet of my section:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView:UITableView!)->Int
{
    return 1
}
```

Picture of my thread stack: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5USNn.png

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see why/when it is being called each time.

Comment: Do you have multiple sections?

Comment: I only have 1. I added the snippet for that code in the edit section of the original post. When I put a breakpoint on both of these guys, it runs numberOfSectionsInTableView() first then tableView(), it does that process 3 times.

Comment: @DougWatkins He better not since the result is based off of a single array.

Comment: In my experience I always see 2 prints to the console. I always chucked it on the method checking for section 0 and then checking if there is another section.

Comment: Per @rmaddy's comment, what is calling these methods? Is it different each time they are called?

Comment: I added println("section is \(section)") and I get section is 0 all 3 times

Comment: @DougWatkins I am setting a breakpoint in the method, how can I tell what is calling them? Aren't these the default methods that have to be set when using a UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewSource protocol

Comment: They are, but there are things you can do that will cause them to be run. When the breakpoint is reached, the stack, on the left side of Xcode, should show what methods called what, all the way to the main().

Comment: Where are you calling reloadData on the tableView?  Each time you call it, the method will be called for each section.

Comment: @JoshGafni not calling reloadData() anywhere

Comment: @DougWatkins I've attached a image to the original post of my thread stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UITableView there are many situations, where different delegate-methods will get called multiple times due to something like auto-refreshing of the tableview.

[Check this answer for more informations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638359/uitableview-delegate-method-called-twice)