# Working with CloudKit Queries and the fact that tableview methods (numberOfRowsInSection) may be called an unpredictable number of times

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Lots of good threads out there around TableViews and the various methods being called more times than expected when building a view.  ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371414/uitableview-numberofsectionsintableview-and-numberofrowsinsection-called-thrice?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144806/why-does-my-tableview-function-run-three-times?noredirect=1&lq=1) within SO to name a few) . Helpful comments - and enough for me to avoid trying to figure out how to stop it :)

> Instead, I'm here to ask how to better structure my app to avoid
>   inefficiently making cloudkit queries due to how building a tableview
>   executes in practice.

My structure:

- First view controller has a list of courses (each course is made of of weeks and each week of lectures)
- When I click on a course, I then pass the course to the destination view controller
- I first get the list of weeks for that course into an array - then for each week
- I then build the table, using the weeks to define the sections and then query CloudKit to get the lectures for each week

I had designed it such that I'd grab the lectures for a given week in the numberOfRowsInSection call, to have it ready for the cellForRowAt call.  This 'works' - I get the data I expect, in the right order.

However, it is very inefficient as I call CloudKit more than once per week because numberOfRowsInSection (and the other various functions) are all called more than 'expected' when the table is built.

> Do I need to refactor it to loop over the array of weeks and append
>   the array of lectures inside of each week at viewDidLoad instead?  Is
>   there a smarter / more efficient way to approach it?

And more broadly - am I right that any read/write (cloud or database) should probably be avoided within the various functions that build a tableview?

Comment: You shouldn't fetch data in `numberOfRowsInSection'`. You should fetch the data first and then reload the table once you have it

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 for confirming what I was beginning to suspect.  lots to learn :)