# UITableView DataSource method called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My topic name might be seems familiar and it is.but believe me i've tried to get some help from other answers on stack overflow but still i can not understand, why DataSource method loads twice while i'm initialising tableview only once.

> (Xcode6.3)

see my code...

```
#pragma mark- UITableView -
#pragma mark Setup TableView
-(void)setupTableView{
    if(!tblEvent){
        CGRect frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y+55+50,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-(55+100));
        tblEvent = [self createTableViewWith_Frame:frame Tag:1 separatorColor:[UIColor blackColor] BackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] ScrollIndicators:false];
        tblEvent.delegate=self;
        tblEvent.dataSource=self;
        [self.view addSubview:tblEvent];
    }else{
        [tblEvent reloadData];
    }
}
#pragma mark Create
-(UITableView*)createTableViewWith_Frame:(CGRect)frame Tag:(NSUInteger)tag
                          separatorColor:(UIColor*)separatorColor
                         BackgroundColor:(UIColor*)bgColor ScrollIndicators:(BOOL)value
{
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.tag=tag;
    tableView.backgroundColor=bgColor;
    tableView.separatorColor= separatorColor;
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = value;
    tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator= value;

    tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    tableView.separatorInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tableView.bounces = YES;

    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifire];

    return tableView;
}
```

```
#pragma mark UITableView DATASOURCEs
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
//this method called 3 times, i don't know why.? :(
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return totalEvents.count;//this is my source.
}
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifire forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!aCell){
        aCell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
    }

    return aCell;
}
```

```
#pragma mark UITableView DELEGATEs
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 127.0f;
}
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    return view;
}
```

i don't use `didSelectRow:AtIndexPath:` because i don't need to row selection.

**NOTE:-**

i use `setupTableView` method in Successful response of web service and web service is called from `viewDidLoad`. please guide me.

Comment: This seems to be normal. What's the problem if it runs more than once? BTW, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is guaranteed to return a cell, so there' no need to check for a nil cell. Also, there's no need to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView` if you have one section, since that is the default.

Comment: Do u have your `UITableView` in your `.xib` or `Storyboard`?

Comment: thanks @rdelmar for your comment. let me try according to your comment.

Comment: @gran33, i'm creating tableview programatically in Storyboard as you can see. :D

Comment: Oops, That's right :)

Comment: refer this answer   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638359/uitableview-delegate-method-called-twice

Comment: @rdelmar, i tried according to you but it make no difference...

Comment: I didn't say it would make a difference. I was just trying to clean up your code. I'll ask again -- why does it matter if the data source methods are called more than once? What problem does it cause?

Comment: @RizwanShaikh, actually earlier i gone through that answer

Comment: just // reloadData in your code and check the behaviour

Comment: @rdelmar, sorry i didn't  mean that but i'm not sure this issue is normal or not. thats why.. :(

Comment: It is normal. It shouldn't be causing any problems so don't worry about it.

Comment: @RizwanShaikh, same result... :(

Comment: refer this tutorial it may be help you  http://jslim.net/blog/2013/03/22/ios-create-uitableview-with-custom-cell-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in your view controller that could be triggering a layout event (like a change to the table header view or some such)? That would cause it to call the datasource methods more than one.

P.S. SO won't allow me to post a comment to your question...