# When do the table dataSource methods invoke for the first time in the lifecycle?

Tags: ios, uitableview

For example when the `numberOfRowsInSection` method is called **rather than** when explicitly calling `reloadData()`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }
```

I am aware that this method is being fired when reloadData() is called. However I was wondering if anybody know when in the lifecycle these methods run automatically for the first time.

This is a curiosity kind of question if anyone happens to have looked into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tableview Delegate will call automatically  multiple times

1. When call of  `[UITableView didMoveToWindow`]
2. Other one from `[UITableView layoutSubviews]`
3. Change of `tableHeaderView` view

See this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986682/4601900

Answer (score 0):

Normally `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` method is being called in `ViewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

It is automatically called for the first time when the view within which a tableView is contained is loaded by the viewController.